# Enviar informação para rest e disparar notificação

Tags: c#, web-service, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou na dúvida na construção de um **REST**, não bem na construção, mas qual caminho seguir, que abordagem. Veja meu negócio.

1) O cliente pede um desconto.

2) Como o vendedor não tem autorização para conceder determinadas margens de desconto, ele altera uma **flag** do banco para 0(zero). Nesse ponto, deverá enviar uma informação para um serviço REST e este dispara uma notificação. O código da Notificação eu já tenho. Só quero saber se o **REST** é com o verbo **POST** ou não? Normalmente usamos o **POST** para gravar no banco e dessa vez não, usarei apenas para indicar ao serviço que ele deve disparar uma Notificação. Como seria isso?

O que vai para o serviço, pode ser qualquer coisa, tipo, um **OK** ou **Dispara**, não importa, o que importa é que o serviço recebe algo e entende que é para disparar uma PN(Push Notification)

Comment: já pensou ao invés de alterar uma flag, inserir um registro e manter o histórico de todas as solicitações de autorização ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, não tem como fazer isso. É uma base do cliente, não tenho acesso e foram eles que disseram isso, pois já funciona assim, não com App, mas no Desktop deles já é assim. Eu apenas deselvovi o App pra eles(Android) e depois IOS.

Comment: ok. no seu caso, se vai enviar alguma informação pro servidor, usa POST sim...

Comment: Estou habituado(não muito) usar post com insert. Dessa vez não e vai funcionar quase como um get, ou seja, vou pegar o parâmetro e ao receber, disparo a PN. Não vai existir persistência.